# Export data in Excel

Tags: jquery

I need a help.
    I want to export data in excel. 
    i have two different table data.
    i want to show both table data in one excel.
    In excel first table data will get displayed ,below that second table data will get displayed.
    I have try this but i am getting only one table data in excel .second table data i cant see in excel .Do anyone have any idea.please let me know .

```
 Collapse | Copy Code
function getZeroErlangBBHCellGridHtml(dataCollection, filter) {
    debugger;
    var htmlResult = '';
    var tableColumnHeaders, tableDataColumns = '';
    var htmlTable = '';
    tableColumnHeaders = "<tr><th>DATE</th><th>CIRCLE</th><th>TOTALCEELCOUNT</th><th>ZEROERLANGSCELLCOUNT</th></tr>";
    tableDataColumns = "<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td><td>{3}</td></tr>";
    htmlTable = htmlTable + "<div><table  border=\"1\">";
    htmlTable = htmlTable + tableColumnHeaders
    $.each(dataCollection[0], function (index, nqi2G) {
        debugger;
        htmlTable = htmlTable + tableDataColumns.Stringformat(nqi2G.Date, nqi2G.Circle, nqi2G.TotalCeelCount, nqi2G.ZeroErlangsCellCount);
    });

    var tableColumnHeaders2, tableDataColumns2 = '';
    var htmlTable2 = '';
    tableColumnHeaders2 = "<tr><th>DATE</th><th>CIRCLE</th><th>CELLID</th></tr>";
    tableDataColumns2 = "<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td></tr>";
    htmlTable2 = htmlTable2 + "<div><table  border=\"1\">";
    htmlTable2 = htmlTable2 + tableColumnHeaders2
    $.each(dataCollection[1], function (index, nqi2G) {
        debugger;
        htmlTable2 = htmlTable2 + tableDataColumns2.Stringformat(nqi2G.Date, nqi2G.Circle, nqi2G.CellId);
    });

    htmlTable = htmlTable + "</table></div>";
    htmlTable2 = htmlTable2 + "</table></div>";
    htmlResult = htmlTable + htmlTable2;
    return htmlResult;
}
```

Please let me know.
Thanks in advance
harshal

Comment: Do anyone have any idea.please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I get it

```
htmlResult = htmlTable + htmlTable2 + "</table></div>";
```

I just need to change this statement .

Thanks
Harshal